# Why does the mysql insertion in one transaction blocked by another where duplicated key occurs

Tags: mysql, transactions, insert, locking

My mysql server version is 5.7.33-log. The transaction isolation level is read repeatable. The problem displays below:
Session1:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_abnormal_job_deadline` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `job_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `deadline` datetime,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_job_id` (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into tb_abnormal_job_deadline(id, job_id, deadline) values (1000, 100, now());
insert into tb_abnormal_job_deadline(id, job_id, deadline) values (2000, 200, now());
```

Session1:

```
begin;
insert into tb_abnormal_job_deadline(id, job_id, deadline) values (1100, 100, now());

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '100' for key 'unique_job_id'
```

Session2:

```
begin;
insert into tb_abnormal_job_deadline(id, job_id, deadline) values (1200, 105, now());

> 1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

During the lock wait, I use another session to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.innodb_locks:

Session3:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.innodb_locks\G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
    lock_id: 81526:2682:3:3
lock_trx_id: 81526
  lock_mode: X,GAP
  lock_type: RECORD
 lock_table: `mytest`.`tb_abnormal_job_deadline`
 lock_index: PRIMARY
 lock_space: 2682
  lock_page: 3
   lock_rec: 3
  lock_data: 2000
*************************** 2. row ***************************
    lock_id: 81523:2682:3:3
lock_trx_id: 81523
  lock_mode: X,GAP
  lock_type: RECORD
 lock_table: `mytest`.`tb_abnormal_job_deadline`
 lock_index: PRIMARY
 lock_space: 2682
  lock_page: 3
   lock_rec: 3
  lock_data: 2000
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why is the exclusive gap lock on primary index values 2000 locked?

Answer (score 0):

What I can see happening is Gap locking. It is how mysql is designed generally inserts/updates/deletes are intended to auto commit and if there is a delay/latency in committing such transactions then such lock wait time outs are expected to happen. Make sure you are committing all transactions properly else there will be such scenarios where your locking inserts would wait till it runs out of interactive timeouts if not set properly it waits till 28800 seconds i.e. 8 hours or other transactions would simply innodb lock wait timeout.

Details on gap locking can be further found in mysql documentations.

An insert intention lock is a type of gap lock set by INSERT operations prior to row insertion. This lock signals the intent to insert in such a way that multiple transactions inserting into the same index gap need not wait for each other if they are not inserting at the same position within the gap.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

#genexdbsolutions #genexdbs #remotedbaconsulting

Comment: Welcome! There's somthing to do with gap lock. But when the insertion in a uncommited transaction doesn't cause duplicate key, another insertion in different transaction will not be blocked...